# Manipulating "selected" option with PHP

Tags: php, html

I'm creating a fairly basic form, and one of my requirements is to check and see if the values are valid upon submit, and if they are, but others aren't they should default to the original value. For some reason, mine keeps setting the last value in the option as selected, regardless of which option is clicked. Probably an obvious mistake somewhere, I just can't seem to see it. Here's the code.

```
<select name="degree">
<option value="" selected="<?php if ($_GET['degree'] === "false"){echo "selected";}?>">Select a Major</option>
<option value="Arts" selected="<?php if($_GET['degree'] === "Arts"){echo "selected";}
else{echo "false";}?>">Arts</option>
<option value="Science" selected="<?php if($_GET['degree'] === "Science"){echo "selected";}
else{echo "false";}?>">Science</option>
<option value="Commerce" selected="<?php if($_GET['degree'] === "Commerce"){echo "selected";}
else{echo "false";}?>">Commerce</option>
<option value="Economics" selected="<?php if($_GET['degree'] === "Economics"){echo "selected";}
else{echo "false";}?>">Economics</option>
<option value="Engineering" selected="<?php if($_GET['degree'] === "Engineering"){echo "selected";}
else{echo "false";}?>">Engineering</option>
<option value="Computer Science" selected="<?php if($_GET['degree'] === "Computer Science"){echo "selected";}
else{echo "false";}?>">Computer Science</option>
<option value="Music" selected="<?php if($_GET['degree'] === "Music"){echo "selected";}
else{echo "false";}?>">Music</option>
<option value="Business" selected="<?php if($_GET['degree'] === "Business"){echo "selected";}
else{echo "false";}?>">Business</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I hope you don't write code in this style!

Comment: I'm actually quite new to PHP. Is there a particular way that it should be styled? (In particular within HTML tags)

Comment: make sure autocomplete="off" on the form element. Some browsers don't respect the "selected" because of autocomplete.

Comment: You could set all your options in a array , and use a foreach() loop so you only have to write everything once, that saves you quite a lot of typing and it is way more flexible. The array can be filled by the result of a database query too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is with HTML, not php. In fact, an option is selected, when it has the attribute `selected`, independent of its value.

`<option selected>`, `<option selected="selected">` and `<option selected="false">` are all selected. Only `<option>` is not selected.

You need therefore to change like this:

```
<option value="Arts"<?php if($_GET['degree'] === "Arts"){echo ' selected="selected"';}?>">Arts</option>
```

Now about the style

- `Do not repeat yourself` (DRY)
- indent your code
- and specifically for PHP: do not change more often as necessary between PHP and HTML.

This would look somehow cleaner:

```
echo '<select name="degree">';
$options = array(
    'Select a Major' => '',
    'Science' => 'Science',
    ...
);
foreach($options as $display => $value){
    echo '<option value="'.$value.'"';
    if($_GET['degree'] == $value) echo 'selected="selected"';
    echo '>'.$display.'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write a function telling you which option to set as "selected"

```
<?php 
function isOptSelected($opt){
    return ($_GET['degree'] == $opt)? ' selected="selected"': '';
}
?>
```

Further in the HTML code :

```
<select name="degree">
<option value="" <?php echo isOptSelected('');?> >Select a Major</option>
<option value="Arts"  <?php echo isOptSelected('Arts');?> >Arts</option>
<option value="Science"  <?php echo isOptSelected('Science');?> >Arts</option>
...
```